# How does the overall energy balance of freeze dried food compares to food frozen and transported over long distances?

Tags: energy

I remember reading somewhere that freeze dried food is not common apart from coffee because the process is energy intensive and expensive. But I just thought that some food is frozen, transported for thousands of kilometres in refrigerated containers, distributed and sold through a specialised logistic that keeps the cold chain intact. What is the total energy requirement of this cold chain? Is it more or less than freeze dried food packaged in a nitrogen atmosphere and distributed at room temperature?

I do not think that vegetable are distributed frozen over long distances, but I think that my question would apply to shrimps or tilapia grown in a farm in Asia and sold in the Western world. Or it could apply to meat frozen in Argentina and sold in Europe.